# Conditionally change value and finding combinations

Tags: r, conditional-statements, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

I have a vector (testCol_1) consisting of 3 letters. Each letter is binary and can be replaced by either 0 or 1.

THE RULE is, if one letter (e.g. S) is replaced by a number (e.g. 1), all the S in the vector will also be replaced by that same number.

I would like to find all the possible combinations; for the following reproducible example, there are 8 possible combinations.

```
test <- expand.grid(rep(list(c("S","E","F")),4))
testCol_1 <- test$Var1
```

My solution:

This is my own solution but as you can see this is rather novice and I am quite sure there are better way to solve this.

```
# Changing to integer
testCol_1 <- as.integer(testCol_1)
# Finding all the combinations first
temp.combo <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),3))
test.final.result <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(temp.combo)){
  testSol <- replace(testCol_1, testCol_1 == 1,temp.combo[i,1])
  testSol <- replace(testSol, testSol == 2,temp.combo[i,2])
  testSol <- replace(testSol, testSol == 3,temp.combo[i,3])
  test.final.result[[i]] <- testSol
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do or what output you are expecting. Are you just going to replace each unique value in `testCol_1` with a corresponding numeric value? If so, `as.integer(testCol_1)` will do it.

Comment: If you want dummies, try `model.matrix(~ 0 + testCol_1)` and `model.matrix(~ 0 + ., test)` for the full data set `test`. But this is generally not needed, R's modeling function create the dummies themselves based on the model formula.

Comment: Not really, for example, in the first combination lets say S = 1, E=0 and F = 0. Then in this case, all S will be replaced by 1 and others are 0. So there will be in total 8 new vectors consisting of 0 and 1. I hope it clarifies.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Not dummies. I actually need to have separate vectors for all the combinations.

Comment: @Rel_Ai I'm counting 9 vectors, `Var1S, Var1E, Var1F, Var2E, Var2F, Var3E, Var3F, Var4E, Var4F`. But this might be because those are the output of the 2nd instruction in my previous comment. As for creating vectors, wouldn't it be `S<-model.matrix(~ 0 + testCol_1); testCol_1S <- S[,1]; testCol_1EF <- as.integer(!testCol_1S)`?

Comment: @Rel_Ai Can `as.list(as.data.frame(S))` be of help? I am not fully understanding the expected output, can you edit the question with an example?

Comment: @Rui Barradas I have edited the question with a solution, which is exactly what I need but I believe there are faster and cleaner ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with no loops, use R's vectorized instructions to get the 0/1 directly from `temp.combo`, by subsetting it, run the following to see it:

```
temp.combo[, testCol_1]
```

Note also that `nvals` is not strictly needed, it only makes the code more readable.

```r
test <- expand.grid(rep(list(c("S","E","F")), 4))
testCol_1 <- as.integer(test$Var1)
nvals <- length(unique(testCol_1))

temp.combo <- expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), nvals))

temp <- as.data.frame(t(temp.combo[, testCol_1]))
test.final.result <- as.list(temp)
test.final.result
#> $V1
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [77] 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> $V2
#>  [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
#> [39] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
#> [77] 0 0 1 0 0
#> 
#> $V3
#>  [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
#> [39] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#> [77] 1 0 0 1 0
#> 
#> $V4
#>  [1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
#> [39] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
#> [77] 1 0 1 1 0
#> 
#> $V5
#>  [1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
#> [39] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
#> [77] 0 1 0 0 1
#> 
#> $V6
#>  [1] 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
#> [39] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
#> [77] 0 1 1 0 1
#> 
#> $V7
#>  [1] 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
#> [39] 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
#> [77] 1 1 0 1 1
#> 
#> $V8
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [39] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> [77] 1 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>